# AsyncTask - error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have problem with AsyncTask in Android. I try to insert data from accelerometr into database, when user push Start. Normally, when user push the button Start, application hanged after 5 second. So I try put this function in AsyncTask, but i have problem with compilation:

```
01-21 17:44:58.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1131): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-21 17:44:58.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1131): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-21 17:44:58.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-21 17:44:58.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
01-21 17:44:58.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
01-21 17:44:58.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
01-21 17:44:58.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-21 17:44:58.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-21 17:44:58.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-21 17:44:58.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-21 17:44:58.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1131): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 17:44:58.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at pl.pawelfrydrych.flyingball.MyTask.insertData(MyTask.java:37)
01-21 17:44:58.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at pl.pawelfrydrych.flyingball.MyTask.doInBackground(MyTask.java:18)
01-21 17:44:58.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at pl.pawelfrydrych.flyingball.MyTask.doInBackground(MyTask.java:1)
01-21 17:44:58.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-21 17:44:58.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-21 17:44:58.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     ... 4 more
```

MyTask class:

```
    import java.util.Date;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private MainActivity main;
        public Database myDBAdapter;
        private int abc;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
   //18 line//          insertData();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d("appname","błąd w doInBackground");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    public void insertData() throws InterruptedException{

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            Date date = new Date();


        while(true){
            long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            abc++;

            values.put(Database.ID, 1+abc);
            values.put(Database.LEFT_POSITION, main.xPosition);
            values.put(Database.RIGHT_POSITION, main.yPosition);
            values.put(Database.GPS, main.GPSposition);
            values.put(Database.TIME, date.toString());


            if(myDBAdapter.db != null){

                myDBAdapter.db.insert("baza", null, values);
                Thread.sleep(1000 - millis % 1000);

            }else{
                Log.d(Database.DB_NAME,"db is null");
            }

        }

        }
    }
```

MainActivity class:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

                switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.bStart:


                myDBAdapter = new Database(this).open();
                        new MyTask().execute();

                case R.id.bStop:

                    myDBAdapter.close();
                    break;

                }

            }
```

Comment: show whole stack trace, to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you get a `NPE` here

```
if(myDBAdapter.db != null){
```

in `insertData()` because you never initialize `myDBAdapter`. You declare it in your task

```
public Database myDBAdapter;
```

but you never initialize it before trying to use it.

It actually looks like you have an `Activity` variable and an `AsyncTask` variable so when you declare it in your task it is a local variable which isn't initialized. You can re-initialize that variable but if they are the same then it would be better to delete it and make sure it is a member variable if the task is an inner class of the `Activity`. If its a separate file then you will need to initialize it or pass a reference to a constructor of the `AsyncTask`  class.

Comment: Yep, I have problem with: if(myDBAdapter.db != null) .. 
So, when I try- Database myDBAdapter = new Database(); constructor should be main? ( MainActivity main = new MainActivity()) ?
Hmm, It's work, but logcat say: db is null :) so it's big success :D

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are initializing  `private MainActivity main;` with anything. You try to use it before it is initialized.